# auto populating values from one sheet to a master sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'll try and word this in a way that makes sense. I've been trying to figure out how to word this for a while and this is the best I can come up with, I hope it makes sense. So I have a master sheet in excel basically tracking miles from different vehicles. And as new ending miles are imported to excel, is it possible to have the ending miles from those specific trucks auto populate to the master sheet? I'm basically a beginner in excel. I know some things but not a lot of things. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Super User please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us all about Master & other sheets along with expected output will help us to fix it !

Comment: You need to provide the sample about import data and the master sheet you need to get the data.

Comment: Is your "master" sheet some kind of summary of the more detailed data entered in the tracking sheet? Sounds to me like you are adding rows of data as they come in eg for a vehicle and mileage on the last journey and need to total the mileage for the vehicle / driver etc. A Pivot Table might be a good way to achieve this kind of summary, but we need to know more about your scenario to really help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Derek.

Can you please clarify why are you entering data in a separate sheet and not straight into the master sheet?

One thing to consider with Excel formulae, Excel is out-of-box good with referencing i.e. the master sheet could refer to a cell in the data entry sheet (in cell A1 put =sheet2!A1), but doesn't copy or duplicate it. So if the data changes in the data entry sheet, it will also change in the master sheet. So as long as your data in the data entry sheet is appended rather than being overwritten (e.g. new rows being added daily) this could work fine. You can of course manually copy and paste cells (which would duplicate the data, rather than reference). To turn this into an automated procedure, you must use macros or visual basic for applications (VBA). Perhaps watch an "introduction to macros in excel" video on youtube. With macros you can essentially create a push button on your spreadsheet (or a shortcut key) to execute a series of commands, such as copying and paste specific values over to a new sheet. Think of a button that says "update" or "commit" or "save data to master".

Lastly, you might want to look into Data Entry Forms in Excel, which gives you an easy to use form for data entry. Have a look at e.g. this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5soiJ5rsqKc